# Non-xcalib way to reduce display contrast by modifying the video LUT (table)?

Tags: linux

I need a way to reduce display contrast by modifying the video LUT rather than the hardware way. I am not interested in something like xgamma. It does not mean contrast.

Also, I'm not interested in xcalib. It used to do exactly what I'm asking for but it doesn't support modern X11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness .8` does *almost* exactly the same as `xcalib -co 80 -a`. *Almost* because if you want to run `xcalib` again you have to first do a reset (`xcalib -c`); any xcalib run applies the percentages cumulatively.

Note that values higher than 1 are useless (just distortion). Also, LVDS-1 may not work for you. Get your output device with `xrandr |grep ' connected' |cut -d' ' -f1`. Do not ignore the white space (e.g., before the "c").